# MongoDB Atlas peering with GCP for existing cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to set up VPC peering between MongoDB-Atlas and GCP in an existing cluster. But in a peering tab in Atlas, GCP is not enabled and it is giving me a message "There is an existing cluster in this project and private IP mode is not enabled"

Is it possible to set up peering in an existing cluster with GCP, if yes can someone please guide me? Thanks!!

I am using M10 cluster, cloud provider is GCP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to settings and turn on "Connect via Peering Only (GCP and Azure)" option.

[image: MongoDB Atlas settings page]

Note that:

> You can only enable Connect via Peering Only mode in an Atlas project that does not yet have any dedicated clusters. Please file a support ticket if you already have a GCP-backed cluster in a project and want to set up Network Peering.

And:

> GCP-backed clusters configured for Atlas Network Peering cannot:
>
> - Be accessed by using the Atlas hostname from outside the peered VPC. Note that database hosts’ public IPs can be reached over the network if the client’s IP address is on the IP whitelist.
> - Use MongoDB Stitch apps.
> - Use Live Migration.

source: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/